# ASP.NET Web Api - post object to custom action controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, web-services, rest

I have next ApiController

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET /api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    public User CreateUser(User user)
    {
        user.Id = 1000;
        return user;
    }
}
```

with next route

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

and i want to consume this service. I can consume first method:

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    var result = client.DownloadString(@"http://localhost:61872/api/values/get");
```

but i can't consume second method. When i do next:

```
    var user = new User() { Name = "user1", Password = "pass1" };
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    result = client.UploadString(@"http://localhost:61872/api/values/createuser", json);
```

i catch next exception without additional information

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

I have a two questions:

1. What correct way to set custom object to service method parameter?
2. How can i get addition information about "magic" exception like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you intend to send a JSON request make sure you have set the `Content-Type` request header appropriately, otherwise the server doesn't know how is the request being encoded and the `user` parameter that your Api controller action takes is null:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var user = new User() { Name = "user1", Password = "pass1" };
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    var result = client.UploadString(@"http://localhost:61872/api/values/createuser", json);
}
```

Comment: Oh, man, thank you and i what chidrens from you)) its joke)) and can you give me some linлs with docs about WebApi besides asp.net/mvc?